# Не получается правильно создать запрос

Tags: mysql

На данный момент есть запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM shop.gropsandproducts s
inner join shop.products on s.ProductId = shop.products.Id
inner join shop.groups on s.GroupId = shop.groups.Id
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по результату, таблица `groups` связана таблица `category`
по полю `CategoryId`.

Не пойму что нужно добавить, чтобы до кучи еще вывести таблицу `Category` (связав ее с таблицей `groups`)

Comment: Точно также как вы поступили с двумя другими таблицами, используя `JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из всего этого следует (если поля правильные):

```
SELECT * FROM shop.gropsandproducts s
inner join shop.products on s.ProductId = shop.products.Id
inner join shop.groups on s.GroupId = shop.groups.Id
inner join shop.category on shop.category.Id = shop.groups.CategoryId
```